# Is there a way to make a page use my own custom CSS live from my PC?

Tags: css

Like the title says, is there a way to have a CSS file on my machine and make it so that when I open a page for example Google/facebook/Youtube, something not made by me, that page uses my CSS to override existing styles, much like when you use the inspect tool or Firebug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to checkout the extension Stylish, which is available for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/stylish/) and for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe). That allows you to define your own styles for specific websites, so it should do exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks, exactly what i wanted, the extension is available for google chrome as well :)

Comment: So if that's what you wanted, you may accept my answer. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm new here :)